# Is there a way to stack the widgets from bottom in linearlayout?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

When defining a `Linearlayout`, the widgets like `Button`, `Edittext` will get stacked from the top.
For example, the below code will display like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuJSQ.png)

```
    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:text="edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:text="edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to add the buttons and edittexts starting from the bottom of the layout without using `layout_weight`?

Answer (score 0):

add `android:gravity="bottom"` to your root layout :

```
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" \\ add this line
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="edittext" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="edittext" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is fine but, the first button moves up after adding the rest. How to resolve that?

Comment: It is the same code you have posted I am getting this issue!!

Comment: my mean is your activity!